# Cannot enqueue query after tafal error when inserting data to a table

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

This error shows up when i try to insert data into a MySQL table. it works fine when i run it on windows, but when running the code on linux the error shows up. am i missing something? here's my code:

```
data2 = { item_id: '1', item_name:'ABC' } 

connection.query("INSERT INTO item_records SET ?", [data2], function (err, result) { 
   if(err)
        { console.log(err); }
   else
        { console.log("success!"); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the sqlconfig file must be the same with the credentials of the mysql in the server.